# javascript prototypical inheritance confused

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

given the standard way of achieving inheritance like this

```
function BaseClass() {

}

function SubClass() {
    BaseClass.call(this);
}

SubClass.prototype = Object.create(BaseClass.prototype);
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;
```

why is necesary to do

```
SubClass.prototype = Object.create(BaseClass.prototype);
```

and end up with something like

```
function F(){}
F.prototype = BaseClass.prototype;
SubClass.prototype = new F();
```

instead of just doing

```
Subclass.prototype = BaseClass.prototype;
```

Comment: If you just do `Subclass.prototype = BaseClass.prototype` then Sub and Base will have the same prototype - that is, their prototype property will refer to the same object. The other techniques you mention make Sub's prototype a separate object, which is what one would normally want.

Comment: If you are familiar with OO from other languages. I strongly suggest you name your functions `BaseConstructor()` and `SubConstructor()` because that's what they are. The prototypes are the actual "classes", the functions are constructors. This makes it easier to think about javascript. Where in other languages the constructor belongs to a class, in js the class(prototype) belongs to the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning values to things in JavaScript really just *copies a reference* (unless working with primitive types). So when you do this:

```
Subclass.prototype = BaseClass.prototype;
```

What you're *really* doing is assigning the prototype of `SubClass` to the same location in memory as the prototype of `BaseClass`, therefore any prototype related changes you make to `SubClass` will also affect `BaseClass`. Here's a little example:

```
function BaseClass() {

}

function SubClass() {
    BaseClass.call(this);
}

SubClass.prototype = BaseClass.prototype;
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;

SubClass.prototype.subClassFunction = function(){
    console.log("Added this to SubClass");
}

var baseObj = new BaseClass();
baseObj.subClassFunction(); // => "Added this to SubClass"
```

---

That's why you want to use

```
SubClass.prototype = Object.create(BaseClass.prototype);
```

because it will create a *new* and *unique* object with the specified prototype instead.

You can read more about how this function works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

Answer (score 0):

## Object Reference!

Say `BaseClass` has a method `toString`:

```
BaseClass.prototype.toString = function() {
  return 'foo'
}
```

But you redefine the `toString` method in `SubClass`:

```
SubClass.prototype.toString = function() {
  return 'bar'
}
```

You'll expect:

```
var b = new BaseClass(), s = new SubClass()
b.toString() //=> 'foo'
s.toString() //=> 'bar'
```

But if you use assignment to create inheritance what you will get is:

```
var b = new BaseClass(), s = new SubClass()
b.toString() //=> 'bar'
s.toString() //=> 'bar'
```

Because `BaseClass.prototype` and `SubClass.prototype` now **reference the same object**

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of JavaScript can be somewhat confusing. In JS, there isn't class inheritance but instance-based inheritance. An instance's parent is also called its prototype.

When you write `instance.something` or `instance['something']`, the JS engine looks at the instance to see if it has a member called `something`. If it doesn't, then it looks at the instance's prototype. If that object doesn't have the member `something`, it looks at the prototype's prototype, again and again until it finds the property or reaches an instance which inherits from `null`. In that case it will simply return `undefined`.

**Functions have a special property called `prototype` which is something else.** The function's `.prototype` is a simple object that has a `constructor` property which refers back to the function itself. When you create an object with the `new` keyword, that object's prototype will be set to the function's `.prototype` property. This is where the confusion comes from: the `.prototype` property of a constructor can be seen as the default prototype of all instances made with said constructor.

So when you add methods to a class by writing something like this:

```
MyClass.prototype.foo = function() {
  alert('foo');
};
```

...you're actually storing the function in the prototype of all MyClass instances. When the JS engine looks at the instances of MyClass, it will look for the `foo` member which it won't find. Then it will look at the instance's prototype which happens to be set to `MyClass.prototype` and it will find the `foo` member and fetch it.

It's important to make the difference between an instance's prototype and a function's `.prototype`, but most people don't realize it. When they speak of a class's prototype, they're talking about `MyClass.prototype`. The instance prototype is accessible via `__proto__` in many browsers, but that's not a standard feature of JavaScript and shouldn't be used in your code.

Now let's look at the code you're using to simulate class inheritance.

```
SubClass.prototype = Object.create(BaseClass.prototype);
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;
```

`Object.create(parent)` can be seen as a function that does this:

```
return {
  __proto__ : parent
};
```

In other words, it creates a blank Object whose prototype is the passed object. Since all SubClass instances will inherit from `Subclass.prototype`, replacing `SubClass.prototype` with an object that inherits from `BaseClass.prototype` makes sure all SubClass instances also inherit from BaseClass.

[image: Sample MyClass.prototype console inspection]

However, as I said earlier, the default `.prototype` attribute of a function is an empty object whose `.constructor` is set to the function itself. So by manually setting the `.constructor` again, we're perfectly mimicking default prototype behavior. If we don't do that, then `instance.constructor` will return the first defined `.constructor` property down the prototype chain, which will be `BaseClass`. It doesn't really change anything in terms of behavior unless our code actually depends on the `constructor` property, but it's safer to have it.

As a final note, like others mentioned before I could finally post this answer, you can't just do `SubClass.prototype = BaseClass.prototype;` because then you wouldn't be able to add methods to the SubClass without adding them to the BaseClass.

Comment: Note: the Mozilla Developper Network calls the instance prototype `[[Prototype]]` to differentiate it from `MyClass.prototype` and to avoid encouraging the use of `__proto__`

Answer (score 0):

**Inheritance, the __proto__** **:**

When an object **`SubClass`** inherits from another object **`BaseClass`**, in JavaScript that means that there is a special property `SubClass.__proto__ = BaseClass`.

**Code :**

```
function BaseClass() {
}

function SubClass() {
}

var BaseClass = new BaseClass();
var SubClass = new SubClass();

BaseClass.a = 5;
SubClass.b = 10;

SubClass.__proto__ = BaseClass;

console.log(SubClass);
```

**Output :**

Here, **`BaseClass`** is inherited by **`SubClass`** and `BaseClass variable is accessable through the SubClass`.

[image]

Comment: That will allow static member inheritance, not instance member inheritance. It's not what the question was about.